# How to link a table from front end to back end in split database (MS Access 2010)

Tags: database, ms-access-2010

I have created a split database in ms access 2010, In front end database I have added a table and I want to link it to back end database. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Comment: Export the table to the backend. Delete it from front end, Link it to the backend table you just exported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your back end database, go to External Data > Access (import and link group):

[image]

In the get external data window, browse to the front end database file and open it:

[image]

When you come back to the external data window, select "Link to data source..." and click ok:

[image]

A Link Tables window will appear, this will list the tables available from the front end database you just linked to. Select the table(s) you want to link to and click ok:

[image]

The table(s) you selected from the front end database should now show in the Navigation to the left:

[image]

...note the difference in the icons in the above screenshot (linked tables get a little blue arrow; local ones do not).

Comment: Thanks Matt Hall for the quick response

Comment: You're welcome. Does this answer your question? If so please mark as answer :)